# Can I tell magit to show untracked files with a repo .git/config that tells it not to?

Tags: magit, magit-status

In my repo's `.git/config` I have `status.showUntrackedFiles` set to `no` (for performance, because it's a very large repo).

However, sometimes (e.g. before I push to remote) I'd like to manually check, from magit, if there are untracked files.

Can I tell magit to ignore the behavior from my repo's git config, and show me the untracked files?

### Alternatives I've tried

- Just use `git status -u` from the command line to get the untracked files (this is fine, but it'd be nice to see this from magit)
- Hide untracked files using emacs (instead of `.git/config`) via `magit-status-sections-hook`, and just call `magit-insert-untracked-files` when I need it (This seems simple enough, but I don't want to hide untracked files by default in all repos, just this one large repo)

### Solution I Settled On

It was too long for a comment, so I'll just put it here.
I modified @whitetrillium's code to preserve my existing `magit-status-sections-hook` in addition to adding the untracked files. That function is:

```
(defun my-magit-status ()
   "Forcibly include untracked files at the end of magit-status."
   (interactive)
   (advice-add 'magit-get :around
               (defun magit-get--around
                   (orig-fun &rest orig-args)
                 ;; (debug)
                 (pcase-let*
                     ((`(,keys)
                       orig-args))
                   (if (string= keys "status.showUntrackedFiles")
                       "all"
                     (apply orig-fun orig-args)))))
   (let ((magit-status-sections-hook (append magit-status-sections-hook '(magit-insert-untracked-files))))
     (call-interactively 'magit-status))
   (advice-remove 'magit-get 'magit-get--around))
```

Then bind this to whatever you want. (e.g. `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x G" 'my-magit-status)`, as recommended by @whitetrillium)

Then I figured I'd just add the untracked files to an existing `magit-status`, and I used the same advice on `magit-insert-untracked-files`:

```
(defun magit-force-insert-untracked-files ()
   "Forcibly insert untracked files (at point) in magit-status."
   (interactive)
   (defun magit-get--around (orig-fun &rest orig-args)
                 (pcase-let*
                     ((`(,keys) orig-args))
                   (if (string= keys "status.showUntrackedFiles") "all"
                     (apply orig-fun orig-args))))
   (advice-add 'magit-get :around 'magit-get--around)
   (read-only-mode -1)
   (magit-insert-untracked-files)
   (read-only-mode t)
   (advice-remove 'magit-get 'magit-get--around))
```

Sort of annoyingly, this performs the insert wherever your cursor is, but it's a nice way to just tack on the untracked files to your `magit-status`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this

***Custom `magit-status` that shows **only** untracked files***

[image: Custom magit-status that shows only untracked files]

instead of this

***`magit-status` (`C-x g`) doesn't show untracked files***

[image: magit-status (C-x g) doesn't show untracked files]

install this snippet, and call `C-x G` (`my-magit-status`)

```lisp
(global-set-key
 (kbd "C-x G")
 (defun my-magit-status ()
   "Forcibly show only untracked files."
   (interactive)
   (advice-add 'magit-get :around
               (defun magit-get--around
                   (orig-fun &rest orig-args)
                 ;; (debug)
                 (pcase-let*
                     ((`(,keys)
                       orig-args))
                   (if (string= keys "status.showUntrackedFiles")
                       "all"
                     (apply orig-fun orig-args)))))
   (let ((magit-status-sections-hook '(magit-insert-untracked-files)))
     (call-interactively 'magit-status))
   (advice-remove 'magit-get 'magit-get--around)))
```

Btw, the `git status` screenshots are taken on a checkout of `magit` repo with following config.

```
~/src/nongnu-elpa/packages/magit$ git config --get status.showUntrackedFiles
no
```

---

I could have used a `:filter-return` `advice`, instead of a `:around` advice.  But I find the `:around` advice more flexible.

Comment: Ah, I see, so we just intercept magit asking what the config value is, and return "all" instead of the value in the config. Very clever :)
I modified this by substituting `'(magit-insert-untracked-files)` with `(append magit-status-sections-hook '(magit-insert-untracked-files))` (to keep my other sections intact), but this funtion worked as-is, thank you!